# domain to www.domain redirection

Tags: redirect, nginx, varnish

I have an nginx server behind varnish and I am trying to do a domain to www.domain redirection .

I tried using these rules on nginx

```
   rewrite ^(.*) http://www.domain.com$1 permanent;
   return 301 ^ $scheme://www.domain.com$request_uri;
   return 301 http://www.domain.com$request_uri;
```

But I get an error in chrome as website running into a redirection loop.

As the about solution did not work I tried an alternative writing rules in varnish

```
sub vcl_recv {
  // ...
  if ( req.http.host == "domain.com" ) {
    error 750 "http://www." + req.http.host + req.url;
  }
  // ...
}

sub vcl_error {
  // ...
  if (obj.status == 750) {
    set obj.http.Location = obj.response;
    # Set HTTP 301 for permanent redirect
    set obj.status = 301;
    return(deliver);
  }
  // ...
}
```

I am using varnish 4 and I get an error that varnish can't compile the code.

```
Message from VCC-compiler:
Expected an action, 'if', '{' or '}'
('input' Line 29 Pos 3)
  error 750 regsub(req.http.host, "^www\.(.*)", "http://\1"); 
--#####------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Could some one please help me in fixing this?

My server block is a follows:

```
server {
        listen  127.0.0.1:8080;
        root /home/webadmin/html/livesite;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name www.domain.com;
#       rewrite ^(.*) http://www.domain.com$1 permanent;
#       return 301 ^ $scheme://www.domain.com$request_uri;
#       return 301 http://www.domain.com$request_uri;     
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        }

        error_page 404 403 /error/eror.html;
        location = /error/error.html {
                root /home/webadmin/html/livesite;
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
             root /home/webadmin/html/livesite;
        }
        #pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9$
        location ~ \.php$ {
                #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                # With php5-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;

                 }
}
```

Comment: could you post your nginx config block

Comment: This is my server block

Comment: is the `domain.com` this same server ?

Comment: Yes I have just removed the actual domain name and placed it with domain.com

Comment: But again I have a problem first time when I fist the home page it still show the site as domain.com when I reload then it changes to www.domain.com

Comment: I think it's a caching issue, clear your browser cache and it might work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a correct way to do it while preserving the uri and the query string,

```
return 301 $scheme://www.domain.com$request_uri$is_args$query_string;
```

The problem isn't in this part, the problem is where you are redirecting to, probably redirecting to another locations that also does another redirect, I would guess you don't have another server block to handle the `www` server separately, so you keep redirecting to the same place over and over, wouldn't know for sure till you post the rest of the config.

**EDIT:**

The issue like I said is that you are redirecting the `www` to the `www` server, to avoid that you should create a new server that isn't with the `www` to do the redirection

```
server { # the redirecting server
  listen 8080; # according to your config
  server_name domain.com; #without www
  return 301 $scheme://www.domain.com$request_uri$is_args$query_string;
}
server { # the actual serving server
  listen 8080;
  server_name www.domain.com;
  # the rest of your actual settings
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use varnish for this instead, and skip the apache rewrites.
This example is to always redirect to https, but the semantics is the same..

In sub vcl_recv:

```
if ( req.http.host ~ "^(?i)domain.com" )
{
    set req.http.X-Redir-Url = "https://domain.com" + req.url;
    error 750 req.http.x-Redir-Url;
}
```

and then in sub vcl_error:

```
if (obj.status == 750) {
    set obj.http.Location = obj.response;
    set obj.status = 302;
    return (deliver);
}
```